# Run multiple threads and wait all to finish

Tags: multithreading, qt5

I have the `Emitter` class that emulates a *heavy process*.

```cpp
class Emitter : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Emitter(QObject* parent = nullptr);
  ~Emitter();
  int start();

signals:
  void finished(int id);

private slots:
  void heavyProcess();

private:
  static int globalId;
  int id;
  QThread t;
  void finish();
};

int Emitter::globalId = 1;

Emitter::Emitter(QObject* parent)
  : QObject{ parent }
  , id{ globalId++ }
{
  moveToThread(&t);
  t.start();
}

Emitter::~Emitter()
{
  qDebug() << "Destruct" << id;
  t.quit();
  t.wait();
}

int
Emitter::start()
{
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "heavyProcess");
  return id;
}

void
Emitter::heavyProcess()
{
  auto time{ QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(1000u, 3000u) };
  qDebug() << "Id" << id << "Time" << time;
  QThread::msleep(time);
  finish();
}

void
Emitter::finish()
{
  qDebug() << "Finished" << id;
  emit finished(id);
}
```

Also, there is a *manager* that creates two instances of the `Emitter` class. I want to run the *heavy process* of each instance and when all the instances finishes, the manager emits a `finished` signal.

```cpp
class Manager : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Manager(QObject* parent = nullptr);
  void start();

signals:
  void finished();

public slots:

private slots:
  void update(int id);

private:
  QHash<int, QSharedPointer<Emitter>> emitters;
};

Manager::Manager(QObject* parent)
  : QObject{ parent }
{}

void
Manager::start()
{
  QSharedPointer<Emitter> em1{ new Emitter{} };
  QSharedPointer<Emitter> em2{ new Emitter{} };
  connect(em1.get(), &Emitter::finished, this, &Manager::update);
  connect(em2.get(), &Emitter::finished, this, &Manager::update);

  emitters.insert(em1->start(), em1);
  emitters.insert(em2->start(), em2);
}

void
Manager::update(int id)
{
  qDebug() << "update" << id;
  emitters.remove(id);
  if (emitters.isEmpty()) {
    qDebug() << "Empty";
    emit finished();
  }
}
```

In the `main` function I expect to quit the `QCoreApplication` after the `Manager` emits its `finished` signal.

```cpp
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  Manager manager;
  QObject::connect(&manager, &Manager::finished, &a, &QCoreApplication::quit);
  manager.start();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Sometimes I have this output

```
Id 1 Time 1416
Id 2 Time 1096
Finished 2
update 2
Destruct 2
```

That means that one instance of the `Emitter` class is not finished, maybe because the thread is "killed" before it has time to finish their process.

My **questions**:

1. Is this a correct approach to create multiple threads to execute the same process with a different set of data?
2. Why the `finished` signal of the `Manager` is called while a thread is running?
3. If the way I am managing the threads is wrong, could you guide me to do in a better way?

Comment: I get: `Id 1 Time a
Id 2 Time b
Finished x
update x
Destruct x
Finished y
update y
Destruct y
Empty`

Comment: @eyllanesc which compiler are you using?

Comment: g++ compiler....

Comment: Well I am using GCC 8.2.1 and Qt 5.12.2 and never had both threads finish >.<

Comment: I use `gcc version 8.2.1 20181127 (GCC)` with Qt 5.12.2 on Arch Linux. Are you using the terminal of the OS or the terminal of Qt Creator?

Comment: @eyllanesc from QtCreator, I'll test with an external one

Comment: @eyllanesc I never imagined that was the issue. Please let me know your comments about my other questions as an answer to mark it as solved

Comment: For me, your way of implementing it is correct, obviously it is not the only way. Actually the other questions are very open to have an answer because it depends on other variables. Your main mistake is an issue of Qt Creator's IDE, it would be good to report it.